# length of character in redis value

Tags: vb.net, redis

hay, I'm new in Redis. I want to create my own redis-cli with vb.net. I found a reference like this

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text

Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Dim stream As NetworkStream
    Dim client As TcpClient
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    Dim result As String
    Try
        client = New TcpClient()
        client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)
        stream = client.GetStream()

        bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("keys *" & vbCrLf)
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
        stream.Flush()
        ReDim bytes(client.ReceiveBufferSize)
        stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
        result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)
        result = Left(result, InStrRev(result, vbCrLf))

        Console.WriteLine("Result:" + result)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ex.ToString())
    End Try

End Sub

End Module
```

actually it works. but why the result always gives me a length of character? where I can delete or remove it? the result is like this:

[image: and the result is like this]

yeah, because I just have 1 key